# print results out of random generated figures

Tags: php

I'm an ASP developer and now new in php, i got this random generator from the web which randomly generates codes. My problem is when i preview in the browser i get no results

```
 function genRandomString($length = 8) {
     $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()_+\|]}[{;:<,>.?/';
     $string = '';
     for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
         $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
     }
     return $string;
 }
```

Comment: Can you include the call to this function in your question? This is just the function definition, it is not executing the code nor does the function itself print anything to the screen.

Comment: The method looks fine, so the problem is likely to be how you are calling it and printing the result. Could you show that code too?

Comment: when i echo $string i get nothing

Comment: @user6579134 where are you echoing `$string`? Please update your question with the code itself.

Comment: @user6579134 You browser will not echo anything if first character of your random string starts with `<`

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to see the value, you need to call the function and either print out the returned value, or assign it to a variable, like so:

```
$randomString = getRandomString(25);
echo $randomString;
```

or just:

```
echo getRandomString(25);
```